# How to use Point cloud library sample consensus to find planes?

Tags: c++, algorithm, computational-geometry, point-cloud-library

I have a point cloud that represents some surface (like mountain), i'm using Point Cloud Library to read the cloud and visualize it.
I have several planes (not air crafts, flat geometrical surfaces) in the scene, i'm trying to find them using the [sample consensus library that exists in PCL](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/group__sample__consensus.html).

I can't figure out how to use it, should i run with a window over my cloud and check every window if it's a plane or not ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look at [this tutorial](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/planar_segmentation.php) and [this one too](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/region_growing_segmentation.php). They are easy to understand and will probably achieve what you are looking for.